# How to set Iframe src in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create mvc5 project.

I have iframe element in my view and @Model that I pass from controller:

```
@Model.MgPath = here is partial URL.

 <iframe src="http://localhost/mapfat/?WEBLAYOUT=" + @Model.MgPath width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

in @`Model.MgPath` I have part of the URL that I need to attach to the soucre of iframe element.

My quetion is how to attach partial URL?It seems that attitude above is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *string.Format* to build your url :

```
<iframe src="@(string.Format("http://localhost/mapfat/?WEBLAYOUT={0}",Model.MgPath))" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Or the string interpolation (C# >= 6) :

```
<iframe src="@($"http://localhost/mapfat/?WEBLAYOUT={Model.MgPath}")" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Or add a property to your model :

```
public class YourModel
{
       public string MapFatBaseUrl {get; private set;}
       public string MgPath {get;set;}
       public string MgPathURL => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MgPath) ? string.Format(@"{0}/?WEBLAYOUT={1}", MapFatBaseUrl, MgPath) : null;

       public YourModel(string mapFatBaseUrl){
              MapFatBaseUrl = mapFatBaseUrl;
       }
}
```

Than instanciate your model with *new YourModel("http://localhost/mapfat")* and in your view :

```
<iframe src="@Model.MgPathURL" width="100%" height="500px"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks for help.I try to use attitude above to generate relative path on img element:

<img src="@(string.Format("~/assets/images/demo/Logo/{0}",Model.Logo))" width="45" height="45" alt="" />

But it seem to be wrong. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your solution explorer ? I would like to see you folder structure and where is the assets folder. If assets is at the root of your solution, you should remove the tild ('~') but I need to see how you have orgonized your solution to be sure about what's going wrong